# ExpandableListView child item's EditText can't keep focus

Tags: android, android-layout, expandablelistview

I created an ExpandableListView with a quite complex child item xml. It contains a TextView, a Checkbox and an EditText. Part of it is below:

```
 <TableLayout
               android:layout_width="match_parent"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:orientation="horizontal"
               android:stretchColumns="1">
    <TableRow>
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="horizontal"
      >
      <TextView
          android:id="@+id/lblData1"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:textSize="14dip"
          android:paddingTop="2dp"
          android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
          android:text="@string/lblTitle1"
          android:paddingLeft="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredChildPaddingLeft"/>
      <EditText android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:selectAllOnFocus="true">

      </EditText>
    </TableRow>
  </TableLayout>
```

The listview displays the list well, I can see my child items with their corresponding widgets but when I click inside the EditText, it displays the keyboard for a split second and the *focus advances to the next child and hides the keyboard* (the focus is lost, not moving to the next EditText).

How can I prevent that? I'd like to write text inside the EditTexts.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Two settings are required:

- In the UI code:

  `expListView.setDescendantFocusability(ViewGroup.FOCUS_AFTER_DESCENDANTS);`
- In the AndroidManifest.xml for the Activity:

  `<activity android:name=".InfoActivity" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">`

Comment: Can also be done in XML: android:descendantFocusability="afterDescendants"... Took me several hours of searching to find this answer. Thank you @Nestor

Comment: @ShirishHirekodi Glad it could help :)